# Duplicate elements (products) is creating in Swiper function of js in django template

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, swiper.js

I am trying to show some products Django template. I have tried [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/) js class to show those products in a div. There are two buttons "prev" and "next" used to scroll horizontally in those products.

In my Product model, there is one product i have inserted from admin and going to see how its shown in the [Swiper](https://codepen.io/aaronkahlhamer/full/oeVQxQ) div. But its showing duplicates of that one element whenever i am trying to click "prev" or "next" or grabbing by "Cursor"

I got idea from [this](https://codepen.io/aaronkahlhamer/pen/oeVQxQ) link.

## Picture in which my product is shown in the Swiper div:

[image]

## HTML CODE in Django template:

```
<!-- products  -->
<div class="container my-4 bg-white border border-light-dark flex">

<div class="lunchbox">

  <!-- slider main container -->
  <div id="swiper1" class="swiper-container"> 

      <!-- additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">

          <!-- slides -->
          {% for product in products %}
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="product">
                  <img class="photograph" src="/media/product_images/{{product.product_code}}.jpg" alt="">
                  <h2 class="product__name">{{product.name}}</h2>
                  <p class="product__description"><span class="font-weight-normal">৳</span>{{product.product_price}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
          {% endfor %}

      </div>

      <!-- pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  </div>

  <!-- navigation buttons -->
  <div id="js-prev1" class="swiper-button-prev btn-edit" style="top:35%;"></div>
  <div id="js-next1" class="swiper-button-next btn-edit" style="top:35%;"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript CODE:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  const mySwiper = new Swiper ('#swiper1', {

    loop: true, 

    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    centeredSlides: true,

    a11y: true,
    keyboardControl: true,
    grabCursor: true,

    // pagination
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,

    // navigation arrows
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      },
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,

  });

})(); /* IIFE end */
```

Any help would be much appreciation.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

this is php code below: but  maybe you'll get the idea..
`<div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="slide<?php echo $foorloop->current_post_index; ?>" >`

here `data-hash="slide<?php echo $objTestos->current_post; ?>"` all this is producing is
`data-hash="slide1"`,`data-hash="slide2"` etc..

and in js

```
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    hashNavigation: {
        watchState: true,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
});
```